# Не получается перевести числа в байты

Tags: python, python-3.x, шифрование, rsa

Я пытаюсь реализовать алгоритм шифрования RSA.

На выходе получается зашифрованный текст в виде чисел. Но я хочу чтобы получился не просто набор цифр, а что то похожее на зашифрованный текст.

Спросив на форуме мне сказали "Лол, ну в байтах строку отдавай, как обычно и делают". НО в байтах это выглядет `"\xb0\x04"` вот так, это число `1200`. И это не похоже на те зашифрованные строки как в онлайн шифровщиках.

Я и подумал что что-то делаю не так. Подскажите как трансформировать числа чтобы было что-то похожее на зашифрованный текст.

Вот пример зашифрованного слова "привет" -- `[1108, 4512, 1, 2554, 2207, 3125]`

Comment: Вполне себе зашифрованный текст. "Красивое оформление" никакой полезной функциональности не даёт.

Comment: Если прям очень хочется, то можно каждое число представить как фиксированное количество байт (зависит от размера максимального шифротекста) и склеить их в одну строку. `b''.join(e.to_bytes(4, 'big') for e in encrypted)`. Если хочется ещё красивее, то можно взять base64 от этой строки байт.

Comment: Да,наверное вы правы. Здесь красота не важна

Comment: На форуме вам еще и не такое скажут. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import base64

inputData = [1, 1108, 4512, 1, 2554, 2207, 3125, 7];
wordList = [num.to_bytes(2, byteorder='big') for num in inputData]

encoded = b''.join(wordList); # b'\x00\x01\x04T\x11\xa0\x00\x01\t\xfa\x08\x9f\x0c5\x00\x07'
b64encoded = base64.b64encode(encoded).decode('ascii')
print(base64.b64encode(encoded).decode('ascii'))


byte_str = base64.b64decode(b64encoded)
restored = [int.from_bytes(byte_str[i:i+2], byteorder='big') for i in range(0, len(byte_str), 2)]
print(restored)
```

> ```
> AAEEVBGgAAEJ+gifDDUABw==
> [1, 1108, 4512, 1, 2554, 2207, 3125, 7]
> ```

Comment: Тогда бы и восстановление исходного показали :)

Comment: Накидал велосипед) Наверняка есть что-то более нативное)

Comment: Можно же было срезами каждое число в строке байт выделять  Ну ладно, это уже вкусовщина :)

Comment: Меня напрягает то, что байтов может быть нечётное число.. Поменял)

Comment: Без намеренной обрезки не может. При `to_bytes` старшие байты будут просто нулевыми, если значение "не занимает" все отведённые ему байты.

Comment: Но на восстановление может прилететь что угодно) В функцию надо lpad добавлять =)

Comment: Cпасибо огромное, это как раз то чего я хотел. Очень помогли

Answer (score 3):

Я тоже немного заморочился, вот вам:

```
encrypted = [1108, 4512, 1, 2554, 2207, 3125]
enc_text = ''.join(chr(ord('а') + int(n, 16) + 16 * (i % 2)) for i,n in enumerate(''.join(f'{x:04x}' for x in encrypted)))
print('Шифровка:', enc_text)
tmp = ''.join(f'{(ord(x) - ord("а") - 16 * (i % 2)):01x}' for i,x in enumerate(enc_text))
dec_numbers = [int(tmp[i:i+4], 16) for i in range(0, len(tmp), 4)]
print('Дешифрованные исходные числа:', dec_numbers)
```

На выходе:

```
Шифровка: афефбскрарасащпъашйяаьгх
Дешифрованные исходные числа: [1108, 4512, 1, 2554, 2207, 3125]
```

Берётся 16-ричное представление чисел и каждый 16-ричный символ превращается в русскую букву. Чётные буквы берутся из первой половины алфавита, нечётные из второй.

Comment: случайным образом добавлять +16 =)

Comment: @vp_arth Случайным потом не дешифруешь. У меня уже была идея на чётные/нечётные поделить, сделал )

Comment: Почему не дешифруешь? Обе буквы маппятся в одно и то же. Только буква я в пролёте

Comment: @vp_arth ААА, точно. Я протупил. Это вообще супер ))

Comment: Но переделывать уже лениво, потом ))

Comment: На моей кафедре вас бы побили за "дешифруешь") В русскоязычной литературе "дешифрование" - это взлом, получение открытого текста без ключа. Получение открытого текста с ключом - расшифрование. К тому же, тут не шифрование, а кодирование.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов Слава БГ, я своё отучился лет 25 назад %)

Comment: @vp_arth Попробовал - не, таким макаром не такой прикольный текст получается, как чёт-нечёт, который прям зачитывать можно ))

Answer (score 3):

Ладно. Раз уж тут такой "показ мод", то покажу ещё такой вариант:

```py
import pickle
from base64 import b64encode, b64decode

encrypted = [1108, 4512, 1, 2554, 2207, 3125]
print(f'Исходное: {encrypted }')

encrypted_bytes = pickle.dumps(encrypted)
print(f'Байтовый дамп исходного: {encrypted_bytes}')

encrypted_string = b64encode(encrypted_bytes).decode()
print(f'Текстовое представление байтов: {encrypted_string}')

# --------

u_encrypted_bytes = b64decode(encrypted_string)
print(f'Байты из текстового представления: {u_encrypted_bytes}')

u_encrypted = pickle.loads(u_encrypted_bytes)
print(f'Исходное из байтов: {u_encrypted }')
```